# Xcode 10.2 Failed to Run App on Simulator with iOS < 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, dyld, xcode10.2

I was playing around with Xcode 10.2 since the update and when I try to run my app on ANY simulator with iOS version less than 10, the simulator will not start and crash then show the error below:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libauto.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation 
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:   /usr/lib/libauto.dylib:
>   mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

I tried to create another new project fresh without touching anything, set the deployment target to iOS 9 and run on iOS 9 simulator again, same error was shown.

**UPDATE**

It seems like this issue only occur when your code base contain swift. Created a new project with objective c code base did not crash the simulator. For swift yes.

**SUMMARY**

1. Xcode 10.2 contain swift code unable to run app on simulator with iOS 9
2. I have done all the cleaning and delete derive data and the issue still persist.

Anyone has any idea ?

**FINAL UPDATE**

Apple just release Xcode 10.2.1 and it is part of the known issue for simulator, please refer to the link below for the workaround/fix:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_1_release_notes

Appreciate @russbishop 's reply, answer accepted

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, same Xcode version. Tried cleaning / reinstalling. Even tried some magic with provisioning profile / certificates. Still does not work.

Comment: Does this bug only apply to simulator, or will it also break on an iOS 9.3 device?

Comment: It worked with real device 9.3.5. But not work with the simulator.

Comment: Very good report, thanks for staying with this thru to the resolution.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This is a known bug affecting iOS 8.x and 9.x. You can work around it by creating `/usr/lib/swift` directories in the relevant simulator runtime root.

Downloaded simulator runtimes are located in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`.

For example, to fix the iOS 9.3 simulator:

```
sudo mkdir '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift'
```

Comment: Before running mkdir, make sure that the 'iOS 9.3.simruntime' does not exists already. For me, the '.../RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift' was missing the 'swift' folder. Simply navigating to '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib' and creating a dir for 'swift' fix it.

Comment: I've tried countless solutions and only this one worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

Me also got the same problem when run in iOS 9.0 simulator.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_1_release_notes

Simulators for iOS 9.3 and earlier might fail to launch Swift apps with the message: “dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libauto.dylib”. (49326587)
Workaround: Run the following command in Terminal for the relevant version of iOS:

```
sudo mkdir '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift'
```

For this apple given above solution in that link.

Simply

--> open Terminal

--> Type this line with your required version (In my case i changed into iOS 9.3 to iOS 9.0)

**Ex:** `sudo mkdir '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift'`

--> Enter password

--> Now clean Xcode and run again

This above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

This seems like an iOS Simulator bug. I see this happening on simulators with iOS 12.0 but not on those with 12.4.

Comment: This saved my sanity!! Yes, it seems to be a simulator 12.0 bug only.

Answer (score 5):

Still get this bug with Xcode 10.3. (Skipped over 10.2.)

Comment: It's not Swift 10.3

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue when I was doing unit-testing for `iOS11` and `iOS12.1` on `Xcode11.1`

The solution was to just run the unit-tests with an iOS13 simulator.

Answer (score 2):

A rather annoying workaround: use Xcode 10.1 to deploy on 9.x simulators for now. It's the only way I've been able to get around this.

Comment: won't work if anyone's project is ported to swift 5.

Comment: Yeah great point. Just refer to the top answer and the official work around: `sudo mkdir '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift'`

Comment: "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. 
My issue is the same as this but was building an app for `macOS`.

Running `Xcode 11` project target `10.4` whilst my OS is `Mojave 10.4.6`.

I had to install `Xcode 10.3` and use that instead. No problems since.

My guess is its a problem with OS, `Xcode version` and project target.

Comment: Yep, worth noting that Xcode 11 + Catalina does not longer support iOS9.x simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Having to use Xcode 10.2.1 I had this issue with another library and ended up having to set always embed swift libraries to YES in build settings since the library in question was in a framework file I had.

Answer (score -1):

Updating to Xcode 10.3 has fixed it for me.